# When a content is trying to display to super user in Joomla 3.6.2, its not working with parse syntax error

Tags: joomla-3.x, user

I am trying to show content to super user in joomla front end

1. Showing parse syntax error
2. Is the code correct for using authorise('core.admin')) to find super user in joomla 3.6.2 or is there a more better and secure way

   ```
   <?php //i want this to display only to super users
   $user = JFactory::getUser();
   if($user->authorise('core.admin'))
   {
   <li><a class="modal" href="http://localhost/code/index.php?option=com_rsform&formId=51&form[Email]=<?php echo $this->prodDet->email; ?>&form[Make]=<?php echo $this->CatName; ?>&form[Model]=<?php echo $this->prodDet->prod_name;?>&tmpl=component" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 590, y: 420}}"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/proto/images/contact.jpg"/></a></li>
   }
   ?>
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have some error in your code. Please try this :

```
<?php //i want this to display only to super users
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if($user->authorise('core.admin'))
{
?><li><a class="modal" href="http://localhost/code/index.php?option=com_rsform&formId=51&form[Email]=<?php echo $this->prodDet->email; ?>&form[Make]=<?php echo $this->CatName; ?>&form[Model]=<?php echo $this->prodDet->prod_name;?>&tmpl=component" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 590, y: 420}}"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/proto/images/contact.jpg"/></a></li>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks it works, just a thing more does if($user->authorise('core.admin')) is secure code for checking whether a user is super admin